# Can't install openai universe with pip install -e?

Tags: python, pip, openai-gym

I get this error while I follow the install rule that provides the company. Here is the install [link]: (https://github.com/openai/universe#installation)

showing this error:

```
user@user:~/universe$ pip install -e

Usage:   
  pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

-e option requires an argument
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `.` to tell it to install stuff from your current directory.

`user@user:~/universe$ pip install -e .`